# Auto timestamp on edit:range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am not really good with scripting so I have turned here for help. I have a Google Sheet that I want a cell(K17) to auto timestamp when any cell within a range (A1:L30) is changed/updated.

Only scripts I can find are when specific cells update it will auto timestamp the cell next to it. Here is an example of code I have found:

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 13 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google sheets timestamp different cell ranges on a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266021/google-sheets-timestamp-different-cell-ranges-on-a-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to doing this is to examine the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that is passed in -- your example doesn't do this. Once you can examine the event you can see the range that was touched. Then compare to whatever criteron (yours is being within A1:L30, which is to say in the first 30 rows and in the 12 columns of Sheet1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range;                 // This is what got edited
  var editedSheet = editedRange.getSheet();  // Ranges belong to a sheet
  if (
    (editedSheet.getName() == "Sheet1")      // correct sheet?
    && (editedRange.getColumn() <= 12)       // column L is number 12
    && (editedRange.getRow() < 30)           // We're on row 30 or less
  ) {
      var time = new Date();  
      time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");    
      editedSheet.getRange("K17").setValue(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW I didn't try out the time format that your original code used, but I usually just `setValue` to a `new Date()` and control the format through the Sheets UI. ymmv

Comment: Yes going to use UTC -6

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks!!

Only changed time format: "GMT-6", "MM.DD.YY-HH:mm:ss"

Comment: I noticed on some of the cells that I have "=IMPORTRANGE", the timestamp will not update when those cells are updated. Do I need to add the other sheet into the script to monitor changes on those particular cells?

Comment: That would be the simplest way, yeah.